# Using Foundation Modals with Django

Tags: django, zurb-foundation

I had an html file using Foundation to display a simple signup login template that was working as desired before using Django. I made a Django project and app and was able to get everything displaying as it was before except for modals. The section looks like this:

`<a data-open="signup" class="button">Sign up</a>
 <div class="reveal" id="signup" data-reveal>`

I've used this http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html but it's not actually displaying the modal when I run the Django server.

I also have the following lines in my html page:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "MyApp/foundation.css"%}">
<link rel="script" href="{%static"MyApp/js/jquery/vendor/foundation.js"%}">`

Along with this     `<script> $(document).foundation(); </script>`

These are all in my static directory. I also have tried adding 'foundation' to INSTALLED_APPS in my settings but I get an error saying no module was found. However, I'm using other CSS from foundation and it's working fine so I'm wondering if this issue has something to do with using foundation in my static directory vs. using this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please update your post to show all of the JS / CSS includes you have for foundation.  We’ll also need the in-page JavaScript.

Comment: @2ps I just updated it some. I'm not sure if I included everything you asked for but hopefully it helps.

Comment: That helps.  What it boils down to is that you’re including the wrong JS file.  You want `foundation.min.js` not `foundation.js`.  See this for more details:  http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html.

Comment: Adding:  if you want to use foundation.js instead, you have to manually include the JS for foundation reveal separately.

Comment: @2ps I thought that foundation.min.js is the same thing as foundation.js except it's the minified version, is that incorrect? I also tried using .min.js instead and it didn't solve the problem. When you say I'd have to manually include the JS for foundation reveal do you mean that I'd have to go into the foundation.(min.)js file and manually find the reveal function?

Comment: When in doubt, read the docs!  http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html : ` Before you can use Reveal you'll want to verify that jQuery and foundation.min.js are available on your page. You can refer to the Javascript documentation on setting that up.  If you are not using foundation.min.js and individually adding plugins, include foundation.reveal.js AFTER the foundation.js file.`